# Branch already up-to-date when trying to merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have the following setup right now.
Start:
Branch A: -> current code (main feature branch)
Branch B: -> copy from branch A where we develop subfeature B
Branch C: -> copy from branch A where we develop subfeature C

After a while I would like to sync the branches (because B needs code that is made in C).

Solution:
I merged B and C into A.
Did the testing on A --> was ok.
So now I'm trying to merge A back into B & C.
But when I try to do this, I get an error that B is already up to date (while B doesn't have the code from C).

How come I can't merge A into B/C now?

Comment: Can you show a graphical representation of your tree?

Comment: I made a small change in A. After that I was able to do the merge as described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that branch A was not up to date locally. So I had to check it out, pull changes, switch back to b/c. After that I was able to merge A into b/c...